# Json deserializing with unexpected edge cases

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following MVC action:

```cs
public ActionResult TestAction(string a, List<string> b, List<string> c, List<string> d)
```

and the following Javascript code:

```
var data = {
    a: "Hello",
    b: ["World"],
    c: [],
    d: null
};

$.ajax({
    url: "TestAction",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    //Ajax events
    success: function (data) {
        return;
    },
    // Form data
    data: data,
    traditional: true, // Needed for passing array in data
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

When I look at the values I receive on the server side, `a` and `b` both yield expected values:

```
a == "Hello"
b == ["World"]
```

However, the values of `c` and `d` confuse me:

```
c == null // expected []
d == [""] // expected null or []
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain what is going on. Why are empty arrays deserialized as `null`, and why is `null` deserialized as a collection containing a single default value?

Comment: Look in dev tools and notice what data passed from client request.
Correct data looks like this: "{"a":"Hello","b":["World"],"c":[],"d":null}" (you can aquire it with: JSON.stringify(data) ).
Compare data string and make note where is an error: on client side or on server side. In case of it locates on client side,  you can replace 'data:data' line with above one.